# Identify green highlighted text in brackets - While-loop not terminating?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on debugging a macro that can identify text in brackets (.docx, .doc), that is highlighted in green like such :

[image]

For now it seems to identify correctly when I test it with a single document. The issue I am currently having is that the while loop does not terminate and subsequently makes Excel crash. I was hoping someone could help me to understand why that is and possible propose a solution. I assume that the True values remains True and that is a cause - but I am not certain, and I cant find the solution.

Let me know if you need additional code.

```
Sub ExtractInputFieldsYellow()

Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim wdFileName As Variant
Dim x As Integer 'Internal document comment counter
Dim xp As Integer 'Excel sheet cell counter
Dim q As Integer 'Document counter
Dim Msg As String 'pop-up string, might be unnecessary
Dim stringFirst As String 'used to determine numbered headers


'### User selects files ###
      wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(MultiSelect:=True)
      'If no files selected
      If Not IsArray(wdFileName) Then
          MsgBox "No documents chosen"
          Exit Sub
      End If

'### load wait-userform ###
Load UserForm2
UserForm2.Caption = "Drawing out input fields"
UserForm2.Show vbModeless 'Start wait pop-up'

        Range("B" & 1).Value = "Dokument"
        Range("B" & 1).Font.Bold = True
        Range("C" & 1).Value = "Sektion"
        Range("C" & 1).Font.Bold = True
        Range("D" & 1).Value = "Type"
        Range("D" & 1).Font.Bold = True
        
        Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 50
        Columns("C:C").ColumnWidth = 50
        Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth = 50
xp = 2

    '### BEGIN EXTRACTION ###
For q = LBound(wdFileName) To UBound(wdFileName) ' Loop through chosen documents

On Error Resume Next
    Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName(q)) 'open Word file
    If wdDoc Is Nothing Then
        Set wdDoc = CreateObject(wdFileName(q)) ' if not open, then create
    End If
    
    '1: If no comments in document'
    wdDoc.Activate
    wdDoc.Application.Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks
        
    Dim rng As Word.Range
    
    Set rng = wdDoc.Content
    
    rng.Find.Text = "\[*\]"
    
    rng.Find.Highlight = True
    
    rng.Find.MatchWildcards = True
    
    
    rng.Find.Execute
    
    
    Do While rng.Find.Found = True
            rng.Select

            If rng.HighlightColorIndex = wdBrightGreen Then

            Range("B" & xp).Value = Dir(wdFileName(q))
            
            'Find heading
            Dim numSec As String
            numSec = ""
            Dim wp As Word.Paragraph: Set wp = rng.Paragraphs(1)
            
            ' Find section of inputfield
            Do While wp.Range.ListFormat.ListString = "" Or Not IsNumeric(Left(wp.Range.ListFormat.ListString, 1))
                On Error Resume Next
                If wp.Range.ListFormat.ListString = wdDoc.Paragraphs(1) Then 'STOP infinite loop. GoTo Preamble if you get to the very first paragraph in the doc.
                    numSec = "Før nummereret section"
                    Exit Do
                End If
                Set wp = wp.Previous
            Loop 'End of loop for While
            If numSec = "" Then 'STOP infinite loop. GoTo Preamble if you get to the very first paragraph in the doc.
                    numSec = wp.Range.ListFormat.ListString & " - " & wp.Range 'Set numbered header
            End If
            Range("C" & xp).Value = numSec
            Range("d" & xp).Value = rng
            
            xp = xp + 1
            End If
            
            rng.Find.Execute
    Loop
```

Comment: You need to remove `On Error Resume Next`. This line hides **all** error messages until `End Sub` but the errors still occur. If you cannot see your errors you cannot fix them, if you don't fix them your code does anything but work. Remove all those lines from your code and fix your errors. If you get stuck tell which errors you get and where. • [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling)

Comment: Hello Pᴇʜ, thank you for the assistance. I will attempt what you propose, and return if I find myself in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are programming this in Excel VBA: you mention working in MS-Word documents. There you have an advanced search function, which gives you the opportunity to search for text between square brackets (using `\[*\]` as a search field and having ±`Regular expressions` checked). In top of that, the advanced search function gives you the opportunity to search, based on formatting (I didn't find the highlighting, but I'm sure it's there somewhere).

Let me give you an example screenshot (it's not in English):

[image: Example screenshot]

Comment: Hello Dominique, thanks for your reply! I am aware of the advanced search function, I do already find highlighted text with that - the function resides in 'Formatting' ('Opmaak' I presume?), at the very bottom. 

I am using Excel because I need to process several large documents simultaneously and identify and extract these particular elements to an excel sheet. Hope this clarification is sufficient, I see that my original text may not have sufficed :-)

Comment: So you are using Excel VBA for reading MS-Word documents, while Excel has lesser search features, while you could be using Word VBA (with the extended search features), and putting the results in Excel. :-)

Comment: Yes I am, it might be more prudent to do it the way you suggest - but, I did not think of that at all. I just assumed Excel was the way to do it - this is definitely due to inexperience with VBA :-)